# Change the color of an SVG image based on the x & y coordinates in QML Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, background-color

I am trying to change the color of an SVG image based on the x & y coordinates in qml qt creator?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Image {
        id: svgImage
        source: "path_to_your_svg_file.svg"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        // Function to calculate color based on coordinates
        function calculateColor(x, y) {
            var red = x / svgImage.width * 255; // Scale x to the range [0, 255]
            var green = y / svgImage.height * 255; // Scale y to the range [0, 255]
            var blue = 0; // Set blue to 0

            return Qt.rgba(red, green, blue, 1); // Return the calculated color
        }

        // Update the color when mouse moves
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true

            onPositionChanged: {
                var mouseX = mouse.x;
                var mouseY = mouse.y;

                // Calculate the color based on the coordinates
                var color = calculateColor(mouseX, mouseY);

                // Apply the calculated color to the SVG
                svgImage.color = color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "color"
```